# How to merge these pairs of vertices?

Tags: vertices, topology, mirror-modifier

These two objects were created with an applied mirror modifier. I would like to join them up by merging the pairs of vertices on each row. I tried "merge by distance" but it took no effect. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: 1. You can change the distance when using _Merge > By Distance_ (can result in not being merged in the center). 2. Another possibility would be to scale them to 0 on the mirrored axis (looks like X in this case) by pressing S, X, 0, Return and afterwards try _Merge_ again. 3. Use the _Bridge Edge Loops_ tool like described by @moonboots

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann okay. Thank you for the additional information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> (shortcut for the *Edge* operations) > *Bridge Edge Loops*:

[image]

Then enable the *Merge* option in the *Operator Box*:

[image]

Comment: thank you moonboots, that was perfect. I will accept your answer once the timer is up