# Is there a better way to merge these vertices other than manually doing one pair at a time?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, geometry, topology

Update: Sorry there was a mistake I didn’t notice that the planes on both sides weren’t at the same position on the Y axis (been in ortho view the entire time). I have since moved them to the same level and Merge by Distance is working now. Should I delete this question?

---

I need to merge these pairs of vertices (each with the one immediately next to it). So far I have been doing it manually (select two at a time and merge them at centre), which works for this model but in the future what if there is something with a huge number of these pairs?

[image: question image]

I tried Merge By Distance and used various values for the Merge Distance but they ended up either not merging at all or giving me unexpected results

[image: unexpected result1]
[image: unexpected result2]

---

Last time ([How to merge these pairs of vertices?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304344/how-to-merge-these-pairs-of-vertices)) the solution was Bridge Edge Loops and it worked really well.

This time, the situation is slightly different because it's two perfect circles this time. I want to have roughly the same poly density everywhere on this object, so I tried moving the left edges back and then using Bridge Edge Loops, but then I still had to eyeball adjust them afterwards (I really don't want to eyeball things if I can make them precise to begin with)

[image]

How do I merge these pairs without having to do it manually each at a time?

Comment: Hello what do you need to adjust afterwards?

Comment: @moonboots the shapes are a series of circles with a common centre, so each pair of vertices would need to be on a straight line pointing to the centre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood you right, you can do this:

select the vertices you wanna merge:

[image]

then bridge edge loops as you know it:

[image]

select the old vertices:

[image]

then dissolve edges

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this could work, thanks. Although I did just merge by distance the other day. I’ll keep your method in mind I think I will need it at some point